# Добавление элементов в state циклом

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yandex-metrika-api

Как добавлять новые данные в `state`?
Вот код:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MetricaGoals extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      metricaGoalsList : []
      metricaGoalsData : []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {

    const OATH_TOKEN = 'token';
    const PROJECT_ID = '23077159';

    fetch(`https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/management/v1/counter/23077159/goals
      ?oauth_token=${OATH_TOKEN}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const DATA = data.goals
      this.setState({
        metricaGoalsList: DATA
      })
    });

    let acc = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.metricaGoals.metricaGoalsList.length; i++) {
      fetch(`https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/data/bytime
        ?date1=2018-06-13
        &date2=2018-07-13
        &group=day
        &metrics=ym:s:goal${this.state.metricaGoals.metricaGoalsList.id}conversionRate,
          ym:s:goal${this.state.metricaGoals.metricaGoalsList.id}reaches
        &id=${PROJECT_ID}
        &oauth_token=${OATH_TOKEN}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        acc.push(data.data[0].metrics)
        this.setState({
          metricaGoalsData: acc
        })
      })
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="MetricaGoals">
        <ul className="goals__list">
          {
            this.state.metricaGoals.metricaGoalsList.map(i => {
              return (
                <li key={i.id} className="goals__item">
                    {this.state.metricaGoalsData[0]}
                </li>
              )
            })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MetricaGoals;
```

В массив ничего не записывается? Почему? Как сделать так, чтобы записывалось?

Comment: вы не дожидаетесь ответа от сервера

Comment: @ThisMan async/await?

Comment: ну почти, тут у вас несколько мест где нужно дождаться ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - `setState` сам по себе асинхронный, так что если вы его вызвали, это еще не гарантирует, что `state` действительно поменялся 
2 - у вас куча запросов, которых вы не дожидаетесь

Попробуйте, вот так ( в комментариях пояснил )

```
  componentDidMount() {

    const OATH_TOKEN = 'token';
    const PROJECT_ID = '23077159';

    fetch(`https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/management/v1/counter/23077159/goals
      ?oauth_token=${OATH_TOKEN}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then({goals} => { // у нас теперь есть goals
      let acc = [];
      const promisses = []; // массив промисов
      // добавим наши goals которые уже загрузились
      this.setState({metricaGoals: goals});
      for (var i = 0; i < goals.metricaGoalsList.length; i++) {
        // добавляем запросы в массив
        promisses.push(
          fetch(`https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/data/bytime
            ?date1=2018-06-13
            &date2=2018-07-13
            &group=day
            &metrics=ym:s:goal${goals.metricaGoalsList.id}conversionRate,
              ym:s:goal${goals.metricaGoalsList.id}reaches
            &id=${PROJECT_ID}
            &oauth_token=${OATH_TOKEN}`)
          .then(response => response.json())
        );
      }

      return Promise.all(promisses); // вернет нам все значения всех промисов
    })
    .then(metricaGoalsData => {
      // тут уже делайте что хотите с данными, они все готовы
      this.setState({
        metricaGoalsData
      })
    })
  };
```

Comment: А почему теперь если выводить `this.state.metricaGoalsData[0].data` в `render()`, вылетает ошибка, мол `data` не существует? Хотя если вывести `this.state.metricaGoalsData[0]`, то в этом объекте будет `data`. [вот скрин](https://yadi.sk/i/yinpTGG03aQ3qj)

Comment: Видимо, потому что опять не жду. Если выводить `propertyNames` внутри `setTimeout`, то все гуд, но если через `setTimeout` выводить `this.state.metricaGoalsData[0].data[0]` то иногда выскакивает ошибка. Почему? Можно ли как-то без ошибки это все?)